# Is it possible to connect wear emulator to android ICS 4.0 device?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-developer-api

Is it possible to connect wear emulator to android ICS 4.0 device without downloading android wear app from play store on ICS device?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: ok thanks ,Android wear preview app need API 18

Comment: FYI: The wearables use bluetooth low energy which is supported in Android since API 18. That is why API 18 is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Android Wear needs API 18 - Android 4.3.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if it solves your question.